# execute Fetch Result return fault even though request clearly says no fault

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

The permanent store is memory by the way and I wonder if it's reasonable

Here is the 3 line codes:

```
PO(request);
fetchedObjects = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
PO(fetchedObjects);
```

The request object:

```
request: <NSFetchRequest: 0x8eba110> (entity: Business; predicate: (ID IN {"monumen-selamat-datang__-6.19_106.82"}); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; returnsObjectsAsFaults: NO; relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching: ((
        Aliases,
        Building,
        City,
        DistanceGrouping,
        Districts,
        Images,
        LatitudeLongitude,
        OpeningHour,
        Phones,
        Promotions,
        Rating,
        RatingGroup,
        Reviews,
        Tags,
        Tenants,
        URLs
    )); )
```

Clearly as you can see it has `returnsObjectsAsFaults: NO`

The returned value:

```
fetchedObjects: (
        "<Business: 0x8ebf3e0> (entity: Business; id: 0x8c4af70 <x-coredata://0111F3D9-6254-4037-AC80-5FEBECEB2343/Business/p332> ; data: <fault>)"
    )
```

it contains: `data: <fault>`